# To convert a date retrieved from MySQL into the format requested (mm/dd/yy)

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to call the date column from the MySQL database. However I dont know that how could i change the format to (mm/dd/yy). My codes are as follows:

```
<?php
$id=$_GET['ref'];
$sql=mysql_query("select * from politics where id='$id'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
?>
<div class="textleft">


<?php echo $row['date'] ?><br />
<?php echo $row['matter'] ?>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
<!--matter ends-->




</div>
<!--topic ends-->
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the format in MySQL?

Comment: YYYY-MM-DD is the format in MY SQL

Comment: you can always use MySQL to reformat the date.  Look at the MySQL reference documentation for more info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: I imagine that an 'end-user' would normally want to see a date in the format of their locale. For this reason, I would be tempted to solve such problems in javascript (http://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Use [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) of MYSQL to improve performances:

```
select *, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m/%d/%Y') AS niceDate
from politics
where id='$id'
```

Answer (score 0):

you could change

```
<?php echo $row['date'] ?><br />
```

to

```
<?php echo date("m/d/y",strtotime($row['date'])); ?><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the date format when you output `$row['date']`:

```
<?php echo date("m/d/y", strtotime($row['date'])); ?><br />
```